# Atualizando aplicação(C#) em tempo real com o Banco de dados (Mysql)

Tags: c#, mysql, trigger, cliente-servidor, atualização

Estou criando uma aplicação cliente servidor, a aplicação rodaria em varias maquinas utilizando o mesmo banco de dados(mysql) em um servidor online.

Gostaria que assim que os dados de uma tabela fossem alterados, inseridos ou ate mesmo deletados, as demais aplicações rodando fossem atualizadas instantaneamente. Atualmente uso um timer que executa uma verificação de 3 em 3 segundos, no entanto acabo por fazer requisições desnecessárias.

Existe uma maneira de fazer isso? Ouvir dizer que com o trigger seria possível, mas como funcionaria isso? Como faço para o trigger me retornar algo na aplicação assim que um dado for inserindo, sem a necessidade de um comando DML para verificar se algo foi alterado.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 3):

De cara eu vejo duas possíveis soluções para isso: **SignalR** e **MassTransit**. Em ambos casos, você vai precisar de uma aplicação para rodar em um servidor (pode ser o mesmo do banco de dados), no caso do MassTransit poderia ser um windows service, no caso do SignalR poderia uma Web API. Vou falar do SignalR, mas como sua pergunta aqui é mais para saber se é possível fazer isso (e não como configurar completamente o SignalR e colocar para funcionar), irei apenas te dar os passos e prover alguns links para você estudar e amadurecer a ideia.

---

Crie um novo projeto ASP.NET MVC, instale a biblioteca do **SignalR** nele, configure os Hubs necessários e publique no IIS do servidor. Uma ideia seria criar um Hub por tabela, e criar os métodos conforme você achar necessário. Para testar, você poderia começar com um simples (ex: `NotificaAlteracao()`) e depois conforme necessário ir criando mais.

> Se possível, sugiro que você tire um tempo para dar uma boa lida
>   [nesse link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr).

Depois, instale as bibliotecas do cliente de C# para o SignalR na aplicação cliente, e configure o mesmo para se conectar ao servidor, configurando também os *proxies* com os hubs necessários. Para instalar a biblioteca client, execute o seguinte comando:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client
```

Então configure os métodos no seu cliente para capturar os eventos dos hubs, e neles você faça a atualização necessária.

> Para mais detalhes referente a aplicação C# cliente, veja [nesse
>   link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client).

Daí você precisará identificar todos os pontos que fazem alterações no banco de dados e disparar um evento no SignalR do servidor, sendo que o servidor irá propagar esses eventos para os clientes (dependendo de como for implementado, inclusive para o próprio cliente que disparou o evento).

---

Futuramente, você pode pensar em criar **Web APIs** na sua aplicação web (que fica no servidor), para que ela faça a comunicação com o banco de dados, e suas aplicações clientes apenas fariam chamadas às APIs ao invés de acessar o banco de dados diretamente.

O guia dos links que te passei é bem completo, e em um primeiro parece ser complicado. mas na verdade não tem muito segredo, é bem simples. O problema é se você não tiver acesso ao servidor do banco de dados em questão para instalar uma aplicação web, ou mesmo não tiver experiência para publicar aplicações web, mas fora isso é tranquilo.